# How to call a method with multiple arguments with different datatypes as input on opcua using python?

Tags: python, opc-ua, opc

Below i have attached my code and the input arrguments

```
ua_types=[('Name', 'LocalizedText'), ('BatchID', 'String'), ('WorkMasterID', 'NodeId'), ('size', 'Double'), 
         ('Description', 'LocalizedText'), ('ClientHandle','UInt64')]
xzy=mthodsetforcreating_controlrecipie.call_method(client.get_node(Creconres),ua.Variant("hil", ua.VariantType.LocalizedText),
    ua.Variant("hill", ua.VariantType.String),ua.Variant("ns=6;s=6/ProjectData/3", ua.VariantType.NodeId),
    ua.Variant(4, ua.VariantType.Double),ua.Variant("", ua.VariantType.LocalizedText),
    ua.Variant(55, ua.VariantType.UInt64))
```

[![uaexpert view when i call the method][2]][2]
[![attributes1][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Comment: Please when you need to show code use code tags

Comment: Please replace the picture of your code with the text version of it...

Comment: i have replaced the picture with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xzy=mthodsetforcreating_controlrecipie.call_method(client.get_node(Creconres),ua.Variant(ua.LocalizedText("hil"), ua.VariantType.LocalizedText),
    ua.Variant("hill", ua.VariantType.String),ua.Variant("ns=6;s=6/ProjectData/3", ua.VariantType.NodeId),
    ua.Variant(4, ua.VariantType.Double),ua.Variant(ua.LocalizedText(""), ua.VariantType.LocalizedText),
    ua.Variant(55, ua.VariantType.UInt64))
```

You have to pass a ua.LocalizedText object instead of a string.